# aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ cross compiling to arm64 error

Tags: gcc, centos, g++, arm64

I am trying to cross compile cpp codes from Centos 7 to arm64 using aarch64-linux-gnu-g++.

I have installed gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu and gcc-c++-aarch64-linux-gnu.  When I compiled, it gave error of not able to  find the c++ header files.

```
[root@server app]# aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -fPIC -shared -pthread -I /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/include -I /usr/local/ssl/include -I /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/include -I  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/include/linux -L /usr/local/ssl/lib -l:libcrypto.so -l:libssl.so *.cpp
In file included from cms_functions.h:4:0,
                 from cms_functions.cpp:2:
ocsp_functions.h:8:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/socket.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from crl_functions.cpp:2:0:
crl_functions.h:8:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/socket.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from crypto_functions.cpp:1:0:
crypto_functions.h:4:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the package gcc-c++-aarch64-linux-gnu will install only the compiler.

You need to install glibc headers for  the cross compiler of aarch64.
Probably you need to install `glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu-2.24-2.sdl7.2.noarch.rpm`   and`glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu-devel-2.24-2.sdl7.2.noarch.rpm`.  sys/socket.h is present in the second package.

As far as I know, there is no rpm package available directly with the headers of libstdc ++ for centos 7. One solution would be to cross compile libstd ++ directly from source.

Comment: I tried to install glibc-headers-2.17-317.el7.aarch64.rpm but it failed as it is the wrong arch type on my development machine which is x86 running centos.  My system already has glibc-headers-2.17-317.el7.x86_64 installed.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry I didn't see that you were cross .compiling

Comment: I installed the two rpms and It resolved the prior errors. Now it is complaining can not find iostream and cstring header files.  It still missing the c++ include/library files for aarch64?  Thanks.